# Adjustable output power supply for DC DC converter - Custom IC or Digipot?

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply, power-electronics, dc-dc-converter

I want to make a DC/DC supply that outputs between 10V and 28V from a 12V input, the system will need to output up to 20W.  Should I use a digipot to adjust the feedback voltage divider, or are there more elegant ways to approach this?

Cost is not an issue.

Answer (score 1):

Linear makes an IC for this that I've used:

[image]

It is a current source/sink and can be used on any DC DC converter with a voltage feedback control and a voltage feedback range from 0.4V to 2V, it's only 7-bit so it doesn't give great granularity on voltage control, but it lets you adjust levels and it has two gain modes.

Another thing is if you wanted to roll your own current source/ sink with a DAC then you could also do better than this.  Otherwise stick to a digipot (which could have it's own set of problems).

Answer (score 1):

> I want to make a DC/DC supply that outputs between 10V and 28V from a 12V input

so you're probably making a SEPIC to get that range above and below the input voltage

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fNQvNm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

R1 only ever sees a small voltage, so you could use a digital potentiometer there or even a resistor ladder DAC.

another option it to lift the bottom end of R1 using a filtered PWM source.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQ0WOc.png)</sup>

the C4:C5 ratio should be about the same as the ratio of output voltage to feedbasck voltage. if C5 is too small you can get a voltage overshoot at power on.

Answer (score 0):

Because your output voltage range is both above and below the input voltage, you will need a true buck-boost circuit.  Linear Tech (now a part of Analog Devices) excels in this field.  A key characteristic of the circuit is that it has four MOSFET switches so it transitions smoothly from synchronous-buck to synchronous boost as the output voltage increases.

If power dissipation is not an issue, a less complex solution is a simple, fixed-output boost converter followed by a variable (programmable) linear regulator.